# Issue with opening .dialog in JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hey guys so I have a interface where, once a user logs in their info is checked, if the user has not read TOS than the dialog box will open.  My issue is, it never opens.

Code:

```
function run(){
    var url = '/pcg/termsofservice/termsofservice.php';
    showUrlInDialog(url);
}
    function showUrlInDialog(url){
      var tag = $("#dialog-container");
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          tag.html(data).dialog
          ({
              width: '100%',
                modal: true
          }).dialog('open');
        }
      });
    }
    // if user accepts
    function agree(){
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    }
    /******is user declines ******/
    function decline(){

     $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
     /*****run ajax to kill session of current user and return to login page ******/
      $.ajax({ url: '/PCG/termsofservice/declinedkill.php',
             data: {},
             type: 'post',
             success: function(output) {
                 window.location.replace("/PCG/mainlogin.php");
                      }
    });
    }
```

PHP check to see if they have not read TOS:

```
//GET TOS setting if any in place, if so display TOS
$TOS = $_GET['TOS'];

if ($TOS == 0){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'run();'
   , '</script>';
}
```

In the javascript code above - `"#dialog-container"` is only defined if the $TOS variable is 0:

```
<!-- See if TOS is active, if so add these divs for the overlay -->
    <?php
        echo '<div id="dialog-container">
        </div>';
    ?>
```

All this works except, nothing displays.

Let me know if you have any idea whats wrong, thanks :)

Comment: Any javascript errors on the console ? does the AJAX call return as expected ? tried putting an alert in the success function to confirm its working and being called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're calling jQuery methods before jQuery is ready. You should have you run() call inside jQuery's document.ready function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       run();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead this:

```
var tag = $("#dialog-container");
```

use this:

```
var tag = $(document).find("#dialog-container");
```

and change it:

```
tag.html(data).dialog({
          width: '100%',
            modal: true,
            autoOpen:true
      });
```

checkout the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen

and call the `run();` in the `doc ready handler`

Answer (score 0):

```
function showUrlInDialog(url){
      var tag = $("#dialog-container").dialog({width: '100%',modal: true,autoOpen:false });
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          tag.html(data)
          tag.dialog('open');
        }
      });
    }
```

Try this...!!

Answer (score 0):

Your div "#dialog-container" does not exists, if you put that div in your html code for a simple test then works.